# Prompt the user to enter three integers, find the largest of these 3 integers and find square of that largest number

Tags: java

I need to write a program in Java that prompts the user to enter three integer. Among these integers entered, the largest of said integers will need to be found in addition to the square root. I'm just a beginner, and I appreciate any and all assistance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class largest {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        int Integer1;
        int Integer2;
        int Integer3;


        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 3 integers:");

        Integer1 = input.nextInt();
        Integer2 = input.nextInt();
        Integer3 = input.nextInt();

        if (Integer1 > Integer2);
        System.out.println (Integer1);

        if (Integer1 > Integer3);
        System.out.println (Integer1)
```

This is all I have so far, and I'm dubious that I'm even on track. Please, help.

Comment: square or square root of the largest number?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Math.max` as aioobe suggested, but if you want to implement the logic yourself use this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
class prog {
  public static void main (String [] args) {

    int Integer1;
    int Integer2;
    int Integer3;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 3 integers:");

    Integer1 = input.nextInt();
    Integer2 = input.nextInt();
    Integer3 = input.nextInt();

    if (Integer1 > Integer2) {
      if (Integer1 > Integer3) {
        System.out.println (Integer1);
        System.out.println (Math.sqrt((float)Integer1));
      }
      else {
        System.out.println (Integer3);
        System.out.println (Math.sqrt((float)Integer3));
      }
    }
    else if (Integer2 > Integer3) {
      System.out.println (Integer2);
      System.out.println (Math.sqrt((float)Integer2));
    }
    else {
      System.out.println (Integer3);
      System.out.println (Math.sqrt((float)Integer3));
    }
  }
}
```

For anything more than 3, your best off using `Math.max`. The `(float)` part is converting the integer to a float, otherwise the square root wouldn't be precise (as integers are whole numbers

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this and you can use different libraries and data types , I'm not sure you are allowed to use for loop , array or Lists .
Mostly for these kind of jobs you need to use loops, that make it simple and easy to understand .

Here are few different ways that you can do it :
In this example if you need to get more than 3 entries simply modify the number 4 to number of integers that you need to receive from user.

```
int num, tmp = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Enter integer number %d :", i);
        num = input.nextInt();
        if (num > tmp) {
            tmp = num;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("the largest number is :%d and the Square is:  %s", tmp, Math.sqrt((float) tmp));
```

second Way without using the for loop:

```
   int num, tmp = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Enter integer number 1 :");
    num = input.nextInt();
    if (num > tmp) {
        tmp = num;
    }
    System.out.printf("Enter integer number 2 :");
    num = input.nextInt();
    if (num > tmp) {
        tmp = num;
    }
    System.out.printf("Enter integer number 3 :");
    num = input.nextInt();
    if (num > tmp) {
        tmp = num;
    }
    System.out.printf("the largest number is :%d and the Square is:  %s", tmp, Math.sqrt((float) tmp));
```

Always try to use less variables, that's make your application more memory efficient.